# When i am trying to add domain for my repository it says domain is already taken

Tags: web, github-pages

I have created the repository on GitHub that I need to publish as a website. When I am trying to connect it with a custom domain, it says the domain is already taken.

I followed the steps mentioned in this support article and verified domain ownership by adding TXT Record and now it says the domain is verified.

The custom domain `livomclinic.com` is already taken. If you are the owner of this domain, check out https://docs.github.com/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/verifying-your-custom-domain-for-github-pages for information about how to verify and release this domain.